# How can I make the Eclipse content assist case-sensitive?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor, content-assist

Does anyone know of an easy way to configure the Eclipse content assist to respond to the case of the first letter in a fragment? When I start a token with a lowercase letter, I'd prefer not to have suggestions for classes, since I am always referring to a member or variable. It would also be nice for a method name fragment to auto-complete when selection of any suggestion would result in the same text (e.g., multiple methods having the same name with different parameters, and no other suggestions offered).

The preferences for content assist don't mention either of these options, and I'm hoping to avoid writing (and maintaining) a plugin just for small conveniences. Thanks for your help.

Byron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible today. There are a few open bugs in this area, e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25305, you can contribute a patch :)

Comment: Hm, bummer. I really wish Eclipse had support for simple plugins with a narrow scope. or even BeanShell script of some kind. Anyway, perhaps I'll take a look at patching it when I get a chance. Thanks for your reply.